# Where to ask question about chrome and chrome extensions?

Tags: support

I want disable audio autoplay on a site, as it's really annoying.

I have tried to use an Adblock rule for
`xxx.com##audio`, but that did not work. It seems to just hide the element instead of blocking it.

And I also want to find a Chrome Extension which can disable autoplay audio based on a blacklist.

I always ask questions on Stack Overflow, but such kind of question shouldn't be asked there I think. Where is the right place to post such a question?

Comment: Don't know where to ask about rule filters, but you might try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for the other.

Comment: Incidentally, you might try using a URL filter (rather than an element hiding one) to prevent the annoying audio file from loading in the first place.

Comment: As far as I can tell from [the SuperUser.SE help center](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) it should be on-topic there to ask about how to get a certain extension to do the work. (Disclaimer: I'm no regular there, which is why I post as a *comment*.) If you're trying to *find* a piece of software / extension, [softwarerecs.se] is a good bet (though be sure to live up to their FAQ for asking questions, you need to be specific about your requirements, etc).

Comment: @Jeroen  @Alexander O'Mara Thanks. Seems `Adblock` can't competent such work conveniently , so I would go to Software Recommendations

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm only a low-rep regular user on sites mentioned below. Be sure to check their respective FAQ's and tag wiki's to be sure that your question will not be closed.

For questions regarding getting a certain piece of software like a Chrome Extension to work, you could go to **[superuser.com](http://superuser.com)**. Looking at [their relevant FAQ entry](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) I'd hazard a guess your question could be written in an on-topic fashion. But only if you need help with a *specific* piece of software. There's a [google-chrome tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) and even an [adblock tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adblock), check their wiki info for more details.

If you want to *find* a piece of software, and want to find out what others recommend, you can try **[software recommendations (softwarerecs.se)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)**. Be sure to be specific about your needs, possibly even prioritized, include details on software that did *not* work for your task / why you're looking for an alternative, etc.

Other than that, realize that your task (find software to do X), is typically/often even better solved using a **search engine** than a SE site... ;-)